# What is the abreviation for “number of”?

Tags: nombres, abréviations

In English we sometimes abbreviate *Number of* as  *No.* (as confusing as that can be when it is taken out of context). E.g.:

> Number of dogs → No. Dogs

Google Translate tells me the same phrase translates as

> *Nombre de chiens*

Is there an equivalent French abbreviation for *Nombre de*?

Comment: In English, the non-ligature form No. is typical and is often used to abbreviate the word "number".[2] In North America, the number sign, #, is more prevalent. The ligature form does not appear on British or American QWERTY keyboards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Une abréviation courante est *Nb*

Par exemple

> Nb étudiants: 307

Comment: Voir http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/NB

Answer (score 5):

*Nombre* or *nombre de* isn't usually abbreviated in plain sentences in French. Among neat-looking¹ abbreviations, except for “*n. d.*” which would likely be ambiguous, “*nb. d.*” appears to be the only possibility (but classified as a *retranchement multiple* and advised against).

In telegraphic style, outside of a sentence, *Nb* is however often used for *nombre de* (cf. [@rds example](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/5693/79)).

Notice that *numéro* (which is also translated as *number* and abbreviated *#* in English) has a standard and sometimes mandatory abbreviation when followed by a number: *n<sup>o</sup>* (the letter *o* is found in exponent¹), plural would be *n<sup>os</sup>*.

—
<sup>1. More details in [Orthotypographie](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/), or probably any other specialized book on the topic.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such thing in French, though the abbreviation *nbr* can be used if there is a lack of space.

By the way, the *numéro symbol* № (or n°) is rather used as # in English, *e.g.* in *Exercice № 2713* for *Exercise #2713*, than as a shortcut for *number of*.